# Returning a value from a method after application restart

Tags: .net, return-value

This might seem silly, but I'm dealing with legacy code (.Net4, C#) which contains:

```
bool retVal = CheckSomething();

...

private bool CheckSomething()
{
    if(whatever) return false;
    else
        {
            DoSomething();
            return true;
        }
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    ...
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

To me it doesn't make any sense because restart should cause the app to start from the entry point, not from where it left off. Am I right?

**Edit**
`CheckSomething()` does the following: 
- If this is not a ClickOnce app (debug) - return false.
- Manually check for an update. If there's an update, do it (and restart) then return true. If there's no need to update, return false.

Comment: maybe thats why that `whatever` is mentioned, to check if changes have not been saved or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although from a logical point of view it doesn't make sense to return something here, please note that syntactically, a method **must** either `return` or `throw`. If you delete the return, the compiler will complain. You may argue that the function could have been void if it only ever returns false anyway, that depends on the rest of the function.

Comment: Added a detailed description of exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

One Question 
How would you replace your own running exe file from itself

i have done the same for my application 
i check for update continue if no update

if updates download them to some tmp folder with updater.exe in it
execute updater.exe and close current application

updater.exe will replace contents and starts application again.

this is working very fine for me

Comment: using `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.UpdateAsync()`, this is built in with `ClickOnce`.